# Turn query into projection query to save costs

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am a little confused on the difference between query and projection queries (this is in regards to the new pricing which will be in effect July st). Say I have a Kind like this:

```
**POSTS:**
post_id -index
author -index
post_message -index
created -index
```

If I want to query all posts by an author I will retrieve N posts, N being the number of posts an author has written. So if he wrote 100 posts I will eat up 100 read requests for this query. Can I just create a dummy property and then turn the query into a projection query. So I add a property named `dummy` and then I do a query but select only id, post_message, and created (author I would already know if I am filtering by it). This way it would only cost be 1 read to get all these entities. Is this possible to do? Why wouldn't everyone do this then to avoid query costs?

Answer (score 2):

Projections return values from indexes rather than the entity itself so there are [some limitations](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/projectionqueries#Python_Limitations_on_projections).

In your example, you would need to create an index on `(post_id, post_message, created)`, but if you wanted to retrieve properties such as `Text` or `Blob` you would need to fetch the entity as those properties cannot be indexed.

You may also find that if you add properties or change properties you want to project, you will need to build new indexes.  So while it may save you on some entity reads, you make some sacrifices too.

Comment: With the new pricing starting July 1st though creating indexes are free (just the storage of them will be expensive). So as I see it only the extra cost is storage of the indexes (I wont need long texts or blobs) ?? I am more concerned to know if what I am proposing is do-able?

Comment: That's actually an important point: depending on your data and application, you may find a lot of your savings are offset by higher composite index storage costs.